# How to define "TINYINT" datatype with the size in sails.js model file

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I have a **student** table in which I have used the **school_id** column to store the school id of that particular student and **school_id** column should only store the value of 1 to 20. So for me, **TINYINT** is perfect MySQL datatype for the column **school_id**. But I have not found any option to define **TINYINT** in my model file in sails.js v0.12. How can I define **TINYINT** in my model file??

I have tried many combinations but no combination works for me.

```
module.exports = {
   attributes: {
      student_id: {
        type: 'integer',
        size: 1,
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

U can do this:

```
module.exports = {
       attributes: {
          student_id: {
            type: 'number',
            columnType: 'tinyint(1)'
        },
      }
    };
```

or:

```
module.exports = {
           attributes: {
              student_id: {
                type: 'number',
                columnType: 'integer(1)'
            },
          }
        };
```